# Variable scope is changed in consecutive cells using %%time in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy, scope, jupyter-notebook

**TL;DR**

I am facing a weird issue (or I am missing something basic). I have a Jupyter notebook and in one cell there is a variable saved as `numpy.ndarray`, but when I print its type in the next cell, the variable appears as of type `list`. How is this possible? In my machine works fine, in a VM does not.

---

**Detailed description:**

I am working on a certain [pull request](https://github.com/gustavovelascoh/pyswarms/tree/notebook_update_feature_selection) updating a jupyter notebook, and as I having some plotting issues in my current setup, I tried to test it in a different machine/system with updated packages and components.

In my laptop I have Ubuntu 16.04 and this configuration:

```
> The version of the notebook server is: 5.7.4 The server is running on
> this version of Python: Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
> [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
> 
> Current Kernel Information: Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018,
> 13:43:14)
> IPython 7.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

I created a virtual machine, installed Ubuntu 18.04 and use this configuration:

```
> The version of the notebook server is: 5.7.6 The server is running on
> this version of Python: Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
> [GCC 8.2.0]
> 
> Current Kernel Information: Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
> IPython 7.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

Then I identified that in the VM, a variable changes its type from `numpy.ndarray` to `list` with no reason (for me). The variable is `pos`. This is causing me problems as it is used later for indexing purposes

**Laptop:**

[image: Laptop]

**Virtual Machine:**
[image: vm]

What is going on here? Am I missing something on this?

Any hint is appreciated :) Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:**

I've tried another notebook in the VM, and now it's not just the type changing but the variable not reached in a different cell (variable `joint_vars`):

[image]

Should it be some misconfiguration of the environment in the VM?

Comment: Are you sure you ran all the cells in sequential order? Looking at your first cell in both screenshots, you printed the type and it shows numpy.ndarray in both cases.

Comment: That's the weird thing... when I print the type in the cell the variable is assigned, the type is OK. but when I continue with the next cells, it gives me type `list`  in the VM

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr, I've updated the post with a *new weird* behaviour: variable is not reached in the next cell (?)

Comment: That's indeed strange. I wonder if it's anything to do with `%%time`. Try removing that line?

Comment: you got it... I removed `%%time` from both cases and they worked. In the first case, 
 the variable type is ok, and in the second case, the variable exists in the next cell... Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I'm not too sure but my guess is that the magic function only exposes the variables to within the cell itself. Afterall the `%%` denotes **cell** magic. If you want to get the runtimes for each cell, Jupyter has an [extension](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/execute_time) for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the problem here is a change in how scope is handled in cell magics. Your laptop was running IPython 7.2.0; your VM is running 7.4.0. The old behavior changed in 7.4.0 (this may be a bug to be fixed in a future release).

I suspect that `pos` had been previously defined as a list in your notebook. In 7.4.0 (as on your VM) everything in the cell is treated as a local scope. For example:

```
Python 3.7.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 19 2019, 20:46:22)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: foo = "bar"

In [2]: foo
Out[2]: 'bar'

In [3]: %%time
   ...: foo = 5
   ...:
   ...:
CPU times: user 3 µs, sys: 1 µs, total: 4 µs
Wall time: 5.72 µs

In [4]: foo
Out[4]: 'bar'
```

If you run the same thing with 7.3.0, you end up with

```
In [4]: foo
Out[4]: 5
```

Since `foo` was defined as a string previously, the effect you observe is that the type of `foo` (as of cell 4) changes depending on the version of IPython. (Here, what should be an integer changes to a string.) This is more subtle when the types involved are closely related, like lists and numpy arrays in your case. It isn't that the type changed because of the cell; it's that the new value never got assigned, so it kept its old type.

The solution is to downgrade the VM to IPython 7.3.0 for the time being, or to avoid using the `%%time` cell magic.

Comment: Thank for your answer.

Comment: this is one of the reason to not use jupyter

Answer (score 2):

To work around the problem for the meantime, you could explicitly put a `global` statement in the `%%time` cell, so the other cells can see the variable.

```
%%time
global foo
foo = something()
```

Comment: This worked in my scenario, when the variable (modin dataframe) was not defined in subsequent cells at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to restart and run all the cell, as you would do by running python from CLI.